# Sitefinity Sync - Restrict to some content type only by role

Tags: sitefinity

I'm using Sitefinity v11.2. I have created a new role "App Editor". This is a very restrictive role:

- Access to a specific content type (i.e. ContentType1) for view, update, add, delete
- SiteSync only ContentType1

Problem:
When logged in using that role, the SiteSync proposes everything to sync (from pages to all content types). I want to restrict that role to SiteSync ContentType1 only.

- Does SF v11.2 enable that restriction?
- If yes, how can I achieve it?

Comment: does it actually sync those other content types if you try?

Comment: No idea actually, I can't make a test myself as it will sync data to a from QA to PRD environment, which is something I can't do without prior permission (including the risk of messing up data in PRD)